# How to get the shipping address from using sales_order_payment_save_after event

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2.6

I need to save the shipping address while order is placed in my custom table how to i take the shipping address . I am using the event `sales_order_payment_save_after` and did the following codes

```
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
 $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
 $state = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
$countryData = $this->countryInformation>getCountryInfo($shippingAddress->getCountryId());
$country = $countryData->getFullNameLocale();
```

It is not return any result . how to i get the shipping addess

Comment: Order is placed in my custom table means?

Comment: @KeyurShah I have a custom table. i need to save order details in my table while order is placed . so i use the event "sales_order_payment_save_after" . when the event is called i am not able to get the orders shipping address

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

public function __construct(
    CheckoutSession $session,
){
    $this->session = $session;
}
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    $shipping = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shipping->getCountryId();
    $shipping->getCity();
    $shipping->getRegion();
 }
```